# Finding all the functions satisfying particular conditions.

Tags: functions, solution-verification, divisibility, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that for all positive integers $m$ and $n$ the number $f(m)+n-m$ is divisible by $f(n)$.

Now I wanted to verify my solution, which I feel is flawed somewhere, but I can't find the flaw. **Also please refrain from providing any solution to this as I want to figure out myself. Please just point out where my method is flawed.**

***My Approach:***

$f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that $f(n)|f(m)+n-m$

$\Rightarrow f(n)\leq f(m)+n-m$ or $m-n\leq f(m)-f(n)$

So now when $m\geq n$ we have $f(m)\geq f(n)$

Thus $f$ is an increasing function

Now the inequality can be restated as $f(n)-f(m)\leq n-m$

Putting $n=m+1$ gives $f(m+1)-f(m)\leq 1$

Since $f:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$, two cases are possible:

Case I: $f(m+1)=f(m)$. This means that $f(m)=k\forall\ m\in \mathbb N$, where $k$ is a constant

Case II: $f(m+1)=f(m)+1=f(m-1)+2=\cdots=f(1)+m$. This means that $f(m)=m+k-1\forall\ m\in \mathbb N$ where $k=f(1)$

Thus only two functions are possible.

Please help in finding any flaw in it, if present.

***THANKS***

Comment: Just looking at the first line of your argument:  how do you know that $f(n)≤f(m)+n-m$?  If, say, $f$ were a constant, that inequality is false when $m>n$.

Comment: @lulu, I claimed that due to the condition of divisibility. As you pointed out, $f(n)=k$ fails, I agree on that.

Comment: Also I observed one more thing here. From the inequality $m-n\leq f(m)-f(n)$, I can claim that $k\leq f(m+k)-f(m)$. Using similar argument with the inequality $f(n)-f(m)\leq n-m$, I can claim that $f(n+k)-f(n)\leq k$. Plugging in $m=n$, I will get that $k\leq f(m+k)-f(m)$ and $k\leq f(m+k)-f(m)$ simultanoeusly, this means that $f(m+k)=f(m)+k$, which gives me my second function. Would this argument be correct?

Comment: Divisibility does not imply inequality.  $2$ divides $-6$ for example.

Comment: @lulu, yes, but the function deals in natural numbers

Comment: So what?  You have a subtraction.  Really, that line is incorrect.

Comment: @lulu I see it now.

Comment: Other than the obvious solutions (the constant function $ f ( n ) = 1 $ and the identity function), there is also the bivalued solution $ f ( n ) = \begin {cases} 1 & n \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\ 2 & n \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \end {cases} $.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Actually, there are infinitely many solutions :)

Comment: Hint: You can avoid the current problem that the difference can be negative if you consider mainly the divisibility conditions implied by (a) $(n,m)=(k,k+1)$ and (b) $(n.m)=(k+1,k)$